# How to reset git repo on production servers?

Tags: git

My goal is to deploy new releases through git on three nodes inside a production cluster. Unfortunatelly there has been a problem with access rights that I now have corrected. Now I am stuck with the message that git believes everything is up-to-date.

```
@node1:/home/www/test$ git remote -v
production  ssh://fx1/home/git/test.git (fetch)
production  ssh://fx2/home/git/test.git (push)
production  ssh://fx3/home/git/test.git (push)
production  ssh://fx1/home/git/test.git (push)
```

After doing a git push production I get

```
...
Writing objects: 100% (7339/7339), 18.44 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Total 7339 (delta 2262), reused 7077 (delta 2100)
remote: error: unable to create file .gitattributes (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to create file .gitignore (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to create file .gitmodules (Permission denied)
remote: error: cannot create submodule directory MEW
remote: error: unable to create file act_adv_jump.php (Permission denied)
remote: error: unable to create file act_unsubscribe_newsletter.php (Permission denied)
remote: fatal: cannot create directory at 'app_cron': Permission denied
To ssh://fx1/home/git/test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Now I realized that group users do not have write permission to the destintion directory where the hook leads. I added g+w and tried to push again:

```
@node1:/home/www/test$ git push production
Everything up-to-date
Everything up-to-date
Everything up-to-date
```

How do I reset the production servers git repo in order to push again?

Comment: *Is* the git repo on your server up to date, or does it just believe that? If it is up to date, what's the purpose of pushing - are you trying to trigger some hooks?

Comment: yes, I want to trigger a hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a new commit (even an empty one with `git commit --allow-empty`) and push again.

That is better than amending the current HEAD (`git commit --amend --no-edit`) and `git push --force`.